# Typescript filter showing error is not assignable to type

Tags: typescript

This is not working. Shows **error** `Type '(Person | null)[]' is not assignable to type 'Person[]'. Type 'Person | null' is not assignable to type 'Person'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Person'.`

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
}

function filterPersons(persons: Array<Person | null>): Array<Person> {
    return persons.filter(person => person !== null)
}

function run() {
    const persons: Array<Person | null> = []
    persons.push(null)
    filterPersons(persons)
}

run()
```

But this is working

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
}

function filterPersons(persons: Array<Person | null>): Array<Person> {
    return persons.filter(person => person !== null) as Array<Person>
}

function run() {
    const persons: Array<Person | null> = []
    persons.push(null)
    filterPersons(persons)
}

run()
```

Any explanation & are there any better solution? Thanks ️

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first piece of code `persons.filter(person => person !== null)` does not typecheck because TSC is unable to understand that your code is actually narrowing array item type to be `Person`.

You can help it by declaring your filter function as a type guard. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3AQL4EEI63LAbpRsuALzIAFAAdMOagKHIAPiQCuAG1UBKZNSmCcvDGmkiAfMl3yAhMNEg1qjjGUgEYYPpjBVkKHO6TjDGoAQSgoOABPAB4-XCU7dRMNELDImOMzQmJiKAgwZShcC24AOk9vaDE%20WI02R2dXd1woZzEtLOyuEB4ySIAjCFig5FDw6NjFFUTkUQBtAF0ibN6IgaGSiWUMAAsxBM0l4i6eYu7ZYwWZ5HKfIbEVtcDa7ORjrFUIEtUsBgC9btq7AILRAbSAA).

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
}

// notice person is Person return type
const isPerson = (person: Person | null) : person is Person => person !== null

function filterPersons(persons: Array<Person | null>): Array<Person> {
    return persons.filter(isPerson)
}

function run() {
    const maybePersons: Array<Person | null> = []
    maybePersons.push(null)
    const persons: Person[] = filterPersons(maybePersons)
    console.log(persons)
}

run()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ️️

Answer (score 2):

`filter` currently cannot apply type guards, there is [an open issue for this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069).

Comment: Thanks for your help ️️

Answer (score 1):

You could use the omni-powerful [`Array.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to do your filtering instead of `filter`... you can implement most array transformations in terms of `flatMap`. However, it doesn't read amazingly well if you're not familiar with `flatMap` operations.

The trick with `flatMap` to turn it into a `filter` is to return an empty array for items you don't want, and a 1-item array for those that you do want:

so:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
}

function filterPersons(persons: Array<Person | null>): Array<Person> {
    return persons.flatMap(p => p === null ? [] : [p]) // Array<Person> yay!
}

function run() {
    const persons: Array<Person | null> = []
    persons.push(null)
    filterPersons(persons)
}

run()
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3AQL4EEwCuICYwOZDGAAbSFHRRsIDAAoADphwZqAQShQ4ATwA8k6cgA+JLiJEA+AJRqN2vUpDn8RYsigQwXKLkVTlAOhgRODAAWTh5BWQAXid5GOjokzNkAH5kAG0AXWRqDPksyzYObl5+QSgeWUtnV2QEZTBkX2kVZHVNXX1BYxBTCxjMrJdiFoD5LgwAC1k+syK64TFobpkFBwwi9gJKkGqgA)

Comment: Thanks for your help ️️